# Convergence of $F_n$ distributions on a metric space $\mathscr{D}$ doubt

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

$\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $F_n$ ($n=1,2...$) it a sequence of probability distributions. Therefore $0\leqslant F_n\leqslant 1$

$F_n(a)<\frac{\epsilon}{8m}$

$F_n(b)>1-\frac{\epsilon}{8m}$

$\left|\int_{(b,\infty)}\phi\:dF_n-\int_{(b,\infty)}\phi\:dF\right|\leqslant m\int_{(b,\infty)}\:dF_n+m\int_{(b,\infty)}\:dF<\frac{1}{4}\epsilon$

**How can we get $\int_{(b,\infty)}\:dF_n<\frac{\epsilon}{8m}$
 and $\int_{(b,\infty)}\:dF<\frac{\epsilon}{8m}$, given the fact $F_n(b)>1-\frac{\epsilon}{8m}$?**

Thanks in advance!